# Why can't I see "shopping" in a Google search result?

Tags: google-search

I used to use this functionality, then it disappeared. I just though that Google had dropped it, as they do [so many things](https://killedbygoogle.com/). Then, just a few minutes ago, my partner mentioned that she had used it to search.

What gives? She sees it in both Chrome & FireFox; I see it in neither.

[image]

Any ideas? I am currently located in UK, so using Google.co.uk, if that makes any difference.

---

[Update] this functions the same in incognito mode or not. Ditto whether logged in to Google or not.

It was suggested that it might be a plugin.I generally use FireFox (incognito) to surf (not logged in to Google) and Chrome (incognito where possible) for web development (not logged in to Google).

I tried MS Edge, which I have not used since the first day that I installed Windows 10, and then only to download FireFox - same problem.

Any logical explanation for this?

Comment: Could it be a user setting? Have you tried opening google from Incognito/while being logged out?

Comment: Do you have any extensions like Invisible Hand running? Have you tried a factory reset of Chrome?

Comment: Updates to both. I have updated the question to reply to your comments.

Comment: Did you look under "More"? Did you try clearing all your browser cookies? Does Google consider you to be logged in?

Comment: The screenshot shows the " more" (sub) menu. The question states that I am not logged into Google. I am loath to clear all cookies in my regular browsers, but, as the question says, Edge had only been used once (to download another browser) and so ought to have no problematic cookies -- it has no "shopping"menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off your VPN. If your VPN is connected to a country that Google doesn't support ads for or isn't being targeted for ads, then you will receive no Shopping option for your search results in Chrome browser Google Searches. Turn off your VPN, then close and reopen Google Chrome with your VPN disconnected. Then search for what you want and VOILÀ! Google Shopping will be available to click upon getting your Search results!

I also had this problem, and I've seen almost nobody mention this as an answer anywhere! So that's how you get your shopping search results back when using Google Search in Chrome.